# There's an "AttributeError: 'Sheet' object has no attribute 'write'"

Tags: python, excel, parsing

I'm trying to write a value into an excel document and it gives me an error.

This is on Pycharm and I want it to write a value if there is nothing there

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

if sheet.cell(4,4).value == xlrd.empty_cell.value:
    sheet.write(4,4, '120')
```

I'd expect it to just write on the excel document but it isn't working.

Comment: xlrd is a module for _reading_ an excel file, so an `xlrd.Sheet` object doesn't have a `write` method. That's why you have xlwt and/or xlswriter for writing files